# Measurability of the Jordan decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M := M[0,1]$ denote the space of finite signed Borel measures on $[0,1]$
(the dual of the Banach space of continuous functions $C := C[0,1]$ equipped with the supremum norm)
and $M^+ \subseteq M$ the cone of non-negative measures.
For $\mu \in M$ and $f \in C$ write $\mu f := \int f d\mu$.

Equip $M$ with the weak-* topology (which is often called the vague topology on $M$)
and $M^+$ with the subspace topology.
In other words, a net $\mu_n$ converges vaguely to $\mu$ in $M$ if $\mu_n f \to \mu f$ for all $f \in C$.

Every $\mu \in M$ has the Jordan decomposition $\mu = \mu^+ - \mu^-$
where $\mu^+, \mu^- \in M^+$ with

$$ \mu^+ f := \sup_{g \in A_f} \mu g, \quad A_f := \{g \in C \mid 0 \leq g \leq f \}. $$

Consider the map $F : M \to M^+$, $\mu \mapsto \mu^+$.
Then $F$ is not continuous:
The sequence $\mu_n = \delta_0 - \delta_{\frac{1}{n}}$ converges vaguely to $0$ but
$\mu_n^+ = \delta_0$ for all $n$.

I want to show that $F$ is Borel measurable.

Proof:
It is known that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $M^+$ coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\pi_f \mid f \in C)$
generated by the evaluations $\pi_f : M^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mu \mapsto \mu f$.
Therefore, it is enough to show that $H_f := \pi_f \circ F : M \to \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable for all $f \in C$.
So let $f \in C$.
Then
$$ H_f \mu = \mu^+ f = \sup_{g \in A_f} \mu g = \sup_{g \in A_f} \pi_g \mu. $$
In other words, $H_f = \sup_{g \in A_f} \pi_g$.
All the maps $\pi_g : M \to \mathbb{R}$, $g \in C$ are continuous (by definition of the weak-* topology on $M$)
from which we conclude that $H_f$ is lower semi-continuous (as a supremum of continuous functions) and in particular Borel measurable.

(It seems that we heavily rely on the continuity of the maps $\pi_g$ and not only their measurability
since in general an uncountable supremum of solely measurable maps can fail to be measurable.)

Is this proof OK or have I overseen or mixed up some facts?